# pretty formatted code doesn't break into new lines

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to embed a pretty formatted code in a div but it fails to break the code into new line and possibly into tabs, has copied.
I am using this code from here to test both php and html pretty formatted code in the div ([Submitting form, mysql and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682180/submitting-form-mysql-and-php))
I am using the example from highlightjs but it seems not to work for me.
([How to format code in html / css / js/ php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270221/how-to-format-code-in-html-css-js-php)) Here are my html output formats:
[ResultView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCKt8.png) and [HTMLCSSView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS10E.png)

I also added this script above the body closing tag html document

```js
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
```

With the css link in the head tag

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/styles/default.min.css">
```

How Can I make this work perfectly?

Comment: the `<script> src` and `<link> href` are missing the `http:` part of the url

Comment: tried it already that didnt solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `http:` or `https:` part of the URL - currently, your file links look like this:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/highlight.min.js

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/styles/default.min.css">
```

Change your links to look like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.13.1/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

And your code will work.

Comment: I changed it but still remains the same. I have seen where links and scripts are used in such manner I did and it usually shows up in the developer tools that the library is present - for confirmation.

Comment: Well now your libraries are linked - maybe look into the `<pre>` tag for retaining whitespace in code formatting.

Comment: it wasn't working because I was using the input tag to store the data in the database. That was why the pre tag could not do anything about it. I guess the input tag just made it a one-line format when I pasted my code on in it. I change the Input tag to a textarea tag to solve the issue.